# Find source of "NdkCompile is no longer supported"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

We have the following warning message in Android Studio 3.4.1:

> WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been
>   removed:
>   android.useDeprecatedNdk
>   NdkCompile is no longer supported
>   Affected Modules: module1, module2, moduleN

We don't use `useDeprecatedNdk` or `NdkCompile` or use NDK at all directly ourselves, so I assume this is coming from some library we have included. **How can I track down which dependency is causing this warning message?**

Comment: I don't think this is something that can come from a non-source dependency (i.e. it's not coming from an aar or anything like that), so it is in *some* gradle file you're picking up. grep?

Comment: @DanAlbert Good idea. I did some extensively grepping now. Only relevant match was `./.idea/caches/gradle_models.ser`. I wasn't immediately able to find out what the file does, but it sure didn't help to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit: In **`~/.gradle/gradle.properties`** it said `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`.